# Authentication/Authorization process in a website built with ASP.NET Core and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I am having issues with my project, namely the encryption and decryption of the passwords stored in the database.

I have made the object public to be able to use it in the other controller but it has not helped the errors.

You will need to use the route for "Register" in the "Program.cs" file to see the authentication process and where the errors are appearing

This is the GitHub for the project
https://github.com/HNCK10/BulkyBook

Comment: Give a little more detailed information about the problem.

Comment: [I have test in my local, could you share more steps to reproduce your issue ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MAtw.gif)

Comment: If you change the program.cs route from the one it is now to the commented out one, and run the program it should take you through a register and login process, which is where I am experiencing issues

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code for each file is all there, inside the github

Comment: You can click on the previous comment to see that I am trying to reproduce your problem. We need you to provide more information and tell us where the problem occurs.

Comment: You can tell us what kind of expected effect you want to achieve, and you can also update the screenshot or link of the problem in the original post.

Comment: Hey @JasonPan, Please open the project in visual studio, and once you have the solution open, navigate to the Program.cs File, there are two routes defined, one is for the Home Page and one is for the Register functionality, please uncomment the Register Route, and comment out the Home Route, then run the program, you will start with the register view, then be given a one time pin, and then taken to the authenticate view to enter that one time pin, once entered, my program crashes.

Comment: @JasonPan the reason being, I encrypt the one time pin when the user enters it using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, I use 
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context; private readonly IDataProtector _protector;
 public OneTimePinController(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataProtectionProvider protector)
        {
         _context = context;
            _protector = protector.CreateProtector("OneTimePin");
        }
As well as
var encryptedOtp = _protector.Protect(otp);
The issue is in my other controller, I cannot decrypt it, due to it being a "different encryption object"

Comment: I would truly appreciate any help you could offer to get my Register, Login, Forget and Reset Password functionality operational.

Comment: @JasonPan I only see your G.I.F now, thank you, yes that is the exact issue I am having

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of code issue in your project. I try to fix the register feature. And in login method, it also has some issue. When in save `Authenticate` data, you have already using `HashPassword`  method to protect it. So you need to fix it by yourself. Here is the test result in my side.

[image]

1. [You should know how to use `AddDataProtection` in asp.net core application globally.](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/data-protection/configuration/overview.html)
2. You can refer my sample code to change it.

**Program.cs**

```
using BulkyBookWeb.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace BulkyBookWeb
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
            // Configure the use of SqlServer using the GetConnectionString to receive the value of the 
            // DefaultConnection key value.
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //app.MapControllerRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Register}/{action=Register}/{id?}");
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**SuccessController.cs, if not, you can create it**

```
using BulkyBookWeb.Data;
using BulkyBookWeb.Models.User;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
namespace BulkyBookWeb.Controllers
{
    public class SuccessController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public SuccessController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Success(string tempPassword)
        {
            var authenticate = new Authenticate
            {
                TempPassword = tempPassword
            };
            return View(authenticate);
        }
        
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationController.cs**

```
using BulkyBookWeb.Data;
using BulkyBookWeb.Models.User;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
namespace BulkyBookWeb.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

        public AuthenticationController(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
            _context = context;
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector("OneTimePin");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Authenticate(Authenticate model)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Authenticate(string otp,string email)
        {
            var _tmp = _context.OneTimePin.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Email == email);
            // Retrieve email from OneTimePin table using otp
            //string protect_otp = _protector.Protect(otp);
            //var oneTimePin = _context.OneTimePin.FirstOrDefault(o => _protector.Unprotect(o.OTP) == _protector.Unprotect(protect_otp));
            if (_protector.Unprotect(_tmp.OTP) != otp) {
                return RedirectToAction("InvalidOTP");
            }
            var oneTimePin = _tmp;
            // Generate Temporary Password
            string tempPassword = GenerateRandomPassword();
            string hashedPassword = HashPassword(tempPassword);
            var authenticate = new Authenticate
            {
                Email = oneTimePin.Email,
                OTP = oneTimePin.OTP,//otp
                TempPassword = hashedPassword
            };
            _context.Authenticate.Add(authenticate);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Success", "Success", new { tempPassword });
        }
        private string HashPassword(string password)
        {
            using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
            {
                var hashedBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                var hashedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
                return hashedPassword;
            }
        }
        private string GenerateRandomPassword()
        {
            const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var random = new Random();
            return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 10).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        }
        public IActionResult Success(string tempPassword)
        {
            ViewBag.TempPassword = tempPassword;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**OneTimePinController.cs**

```
using BulkyBookWeb.Data;
using BulkyBookWeb.Models.User;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using BulkyBookWeb.Controllers;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

namespace BulkyBookWeb.Controllers
{
    public class OneTimePinController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

        public OneTimePinController(ApplicationDbContext context, IDataProtectionProvider provider)
        {
            _context = context;
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector("OneTimePin");
        }
        [HttpGet]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult OneTimePin(string email,string postotp)
        {
            var otp = string.Empty;
            if (postotp == null || postotp.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                otp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 6);
            }
            else {
                otp = postotp;
            }
            
            //var dataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("BulkyBookWeb");
            //var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("OneTimePin");
            var encryptedOtp = _protector.Protect(otp);

            if (Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Authenticate","Authentication", new Authenticate { Email= email, OTP = encryptedOtp });
            }
            else
            {
                var register = _context.Register.Find(email);
                if (register == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
               
                //var encryptedOtp = protector.Protect(otp);
                var oneTimePin = new OneTimePin
                {
                    Email = email,
                    OTP = encryptedOtp
                };
                _context.OneTimePin.Add(oneTimePin);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                var decryptedOtp = _protector.Unprotect(encryptedOtp);
                ViewBag.DecryptedOtp = decryptedOtp;
                ViewBag.Email = email;
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Authenticate.cshtml**

```
@model BulkyBookWeb.Models.User.Authenticate
<form asp-action = "Authenticate" method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Authenticate</h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
@*            <label>Email address</label>*@
            <input type="hidden" name="email" class="form-control" value="@Model?.Email" readonly />
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label>One Time Pin</label>
            <input type="text" name="otp" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:150px">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
@section Scripts{
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

**OneTimePin.cshtml**

```
@model BulkyBookWeb.Models.User.OneTimePin
<h2>One Time Pin</h2>
<p>Please copy the following One Time Pin:</p>
<h3>@ViewBag.decryptedOtp</h3>
<form asp-action="OneTimePin" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="@ViewBag.Email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="postotp" value="@ViewBag.decryptedOtp" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Confirm" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**Success.cshtml**

```
@model BulkyBookWeb.Models.User.Authenticate

<h2>Password Reset Successful</h2>

<p>Your temporary password is: <strong>@Model.TempPassword</strong></p>

<p>Please use this temporary password to login and change your password immediately.</p>

@Html.ActionLink("Back to Login", "Login", "Login")
```

**Next Action**

You need to change hash your password inside the model, then you can login successfully.

[image]